# How do I most efficiently partition a constantly changing list to calculate its sum?

Tags: algorithm

Say I have a list of 4 numbers, of different values. I have a second list describing the sum of all number to that point (if list1=[1,3,2,5], list2=[1,4,6,11]). This way for a list of hundreds of thousands of numbers, I don't have to add all the numbers - the information is already stored.

If I insert a new number in list1 at index 0, say the number 2, I must update all following values in list2. For very large lists, this gets very time consuming (also defeating the purpose of the second list).

However, if I record the sum of the first half of the list (4), I can continue list2 from relative to that sum (list2=[1,4,2,7]). Now, if I insert the number 2 at index=0, I need only update the first two values and the recorded halfway value. For a list of 100,000 numbers, this would guarantee that I need only ever update 50,000 values.

I can also record the value at every third of the list, or at every 10,000 numbers, or I could record halfway of the halfway (kinda like binary sorting - now I only need to update/look at whichever sublist I am affecting).

Question: How do I determine / what is the most efficient way to go about managing this list? Halves? Thirds? Three levels, each one halving the previous ones?

[This is a practical question, not a theoretical one. List2 provides offsets for laying out and rendering text/graphics. A tree would not be practical in the context I am working with. I must deal with a single list. I need access to any given sum/offset, fast. Also, I am having a hard time presenting it clearly. Please feel free to clarify the question or ask for clarification.]

Comment: Sounds like you might want a *tree* of some kind.

Comment: Thanks. However, while I understand it may not be obvious why I chose my approach, 'why' has little baring on my question. A tree would not be a workable option given the context.

Comment: Do you ever delete numbers from the list?  How do you access the list, do you traverse it in order or do you index into it?  How often do you insert new numbers in the list vs. how often do you access the list?  How large are the numbers in the list?  How long can the list become?

Comment: It seems like the most efficient approach would be to maintain a tree.  Each node of the tree would maintain the sum of a particular range of the list, and the child nodes would maintain the sums of sub-ranges.  The tree could be updated in O(log(n)) time after an insert, and sums could be calculated in O(log(n)) time.

Comment: @PuraVida: I do delete numbers. I access it by index. I access it far more often than I edit it, but when I edit it, I need the updated information quickly. The numbers are generally in the 10-20 range, and the sums can reach upwards of a million. The list is generally in the hundreds of thousands of items.

Comment: @VaughnCato has the right idea.

Comment: You frequently index into the list... are those random accesses or somewhat sequential?

Comment: @PuraVida: They are generally sequential, but can and do jump around at times (the context being a rendering engine for graphics and text, the user scrolls, and a subset of the document is presented).

Comment: @Li-aungYip: I appreciate the suggestion. However, as I said, a tree would not be workable in the context of the program I am working with. Either way, I do believe it is a reasonable question in and of itself. Not so much 'why' a person would need it, but how to approach it if one does.

Comment: The optimal partitioning is going to depend on how often you do insertions compared to accesses.

Comment: Thanks. I would guess its at least 3000 accesses per 1 edit, probably event more. I appreciate the time your are spending on it. Would you be able to present an explanation as an answer?

Comment: Is inserting at index zero the typical case?

Comment: I guess You should clarify why You think a tree is not workable, then we can convince you that you are wrong on this count :).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this, without trees, is to break your primary array into sqrt(N) regions of sqrt(N) elements each.  For each section keep track of the range it covers and the sum of the elements in that range.  Now if you want to find the sum up to element k, you would add together the sums for all of the sqrt(N) sized ranges that come before element k, then add together the elements in element k's range that come before it.  Both of those things take O(sqrt(N)) time, for a total of O(sqrt(N)).

All operations, insert, delete, and query, will be O(sqrt(N)), since in each case you will need to query/modify O(sqrt(N)) lists, and O(sqrt(N)) elements in your primary array.

You will also need to reform the structure occasionally.  Exactly when to do this is up to you, but you have to do it regularly enough or you won't keep your O(sqrt(N)) runtime on those operations.  If you completely remade the list after every sqrt(N) modifications (insert or delete only) that would be sufficient.  That would require O(N) work every O(sqrt(N)) operations, which, amortized over time, would be an additional O(sqrt(N)) work on every operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array (vector in C++), call it IndexSum, that contains just sums (you can infer the value of an element by subtracting the previous sum from the sum).  Arrays can be indexed trivially and perform well for sequential access.  Since arrays don't keep pointers to next elements they are compact and fit well in the processor data cache.  I would keep insertions and deletions in a sorted array (vector), call it InsertDeleteAdjust, that you can easily access with binary search... this allows you to keep track of the adjustment you need to make to the sum in IndexSum for an index range.  You could periodically run a "garbage collection" routine that synchronously updates IndexSum with the values in InsertDeleteAdjust.  If the latency of such periodic "garbage collection" is not acceptable then you can get fancier with asynchronous threads and locks, etc.